# Socket timeout randomly triggers faster than it should

Tags: android, networking, clock

I have an app that is communicating with an embedded device using a custom protocol built on top of udp. In order to verify that the device is still on the network, I have the receiving end of the datagram socket set up with a timeout of 1 second. Should the timeout trigger, I send an echo request to the embedded device and wait another second (if this happens twice I assume that no further communication is possible, and change the internal state of the app to disconnected).

In testing the app, it was noticed that the app would suddenly switch to the disconnected state (This can happen anywhere from 5 minutes to 2.5 hours of operation). No errors occurred on the embedded device, and tcpdump shows that the embeded device responded within 30ms. tcpdump also shows that the final set of echo requests were all sent to the server in under 10ms

[wireshark display of tcpdump data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXLBp.png)

I don't know how likely it is for the system clock to suddenly jump forward in time, but that's what *looks* like is happening.

Oh, and this was tested on the following devices:

- Pixel 2
- Sumsung S9
- Essential Phone
- Some older LG device
- Samsung Galexy Tab 3

The issue has only been documented to occur on the Galaxy tab

Has anyone else noticed issues with timing with this or other devices, where an event will trigger early? Specifically where the system clock will report that more time has passed than actually has? If so, any suggestions on how I can mitigate this? If not does anyone know what else could be causing these symptoms?

Time logs from the udp listener using `SystemClock.elaspedRealtime()` and `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`:

```
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191128173 uptimemillis: 106498062
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191129199 uptimemillis: 106499088
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191130224 uptimemillis: 106500113
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191131252 uptimemillis: 106501141
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191132278 uptimemillis: 106502167
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191133301 uptimemillis: 106503190
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191134325 uptimemillis: 106504214
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191135350 uptimemillis: 106505239
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191136376 uptimemillis: 106506265
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191137400 uptimemillis: 106507289
post timeout: elapsedRealtime: 191138404 uptimemillis: 106508293
pre recieve: elapsedRealtime: 191138406 uptimemillis: 106508295
post timeout: elapsedRealtime: 191139409 uptimemillis: 106509298
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks. I added some actual points that would help me if answered, and simplified other portions of the question

Comment: Could you clarify, does "server" == "embedded device"? And, what is the significance of the statement "...all sent to the server in under 10m"? 10ms? It would also be helpful if you could include a Wireshark screenshot of this occurring with maybe 15s on either side. And, what box is wireshark running on?

Comment: Yes, server is the embedded device. 10m was a typo, I did mean 10 milliseconds. tcpdump was running on a wifi pineapple.

Comment: You mentioned `realTimeElapsed()` in an earlier edit... Could you include a dump of that timing data? I'd like to know the absolute timestamps A.) immediately before the call to `receive()` and B.) immediately after the receipt (or timeout) occurs. So, about 5 seconds' worth of data total. And include `uptimeMillis()` data alongside that if you can, to rule out sleep problems. To partially answer your question, a slip of the handset's hardware clock would be practically unheard of; I suspect there is another explanation for this.

Comment: I'm confident that the clocks are not lying to you, I could expound more on that if you disagree but my space is limited. I also think your tcpdump timestamps are correct, but it is a mistake to assume that those times accurately reflect the relationship of `send()`/`recieve()` timings on the handset -- they merely set upper bounds on them. Much more likely, we're dealing with a packet queueing issue here...

Comment: ...2.2 seconds is a long time for a packet to get delayed; I'll admit it's hard to explain that. It could be a problem with your pineapple, although that's less likely. The packets could also be queuing on your handset! I don't know the linux WiFi stack in sufficient detail, but _just because send() returned doesn't necessarily mean the packet has left the transmitter_. Perhaps the handset queued the packets because of a temporarily radio problem, like a drop in the WiFi signal. Another possibility is that another process on your handset needed to send a lot of data...

Comment: ...I think a good way to proceed is to get an unfiltered tcpdump (maybe you already did, I can't tell) and see if there is a long burst of traffic coming from (other software on) your handset around the time the fault occurs.

Comment: But, even if you find the culprit, the answer to your question will probably still be this: "Digital networks, especially WiFi, commonly experience temporary burbles, due to a wide variety of conditions. The concept of 'am I still connected' can only be defined in terms of timings chosen by the developer. Your app switches into a disconnected state because it has, in fact, disconnected (according to your definition). You can either increase the timeouts (to make disconnection less likely), or find a more graceful way of allowing your user to deal with the disconnection."